# "rake aborted! undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass" message when running rake in cron job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am a ROR noob who has inherited a project (Ruby version 1.9.3p0, Rails version 3.0.6, rake version 0.9.2) which performs a rake as part of a cronjob. This has been outputting "rake aborted! undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass" into its log file. When I perform a trace I get the following output:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
/var/www/nostos-source-illiad/lib/nostos-source-illiad/record.rb:48:in `block in charge!'
(eval):22:in `form_with'
/var/www/nostos-source-illiad/lib/nostos-source-illiad/record.rb:47:in `charge!'
/var/www/nostos/app/models/transaction.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in sync!'
/var/www/nostos/app/models/transaction.rb:58:in `each'
/var/www/nostos/app/models/transaction.rb:58:in `block in sync!'
/var/www/nostos/app/models/transaction.rb:57:in `each'
/var/www/nostos/app/models/transaction.rb:57:in `sync!'
/var/www/nostos/lib/tasks/nostos.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => nostos:cron
```

I am having trouble determining what exactly is causing this issue and was looking for some advice/direction. I do not think this is caused by the same issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623983/rake-undefined-method-for-nilnilclass) but I am not definite. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:
Code for `nostos:rake`can be found [here](https://github.com/bricestacey/nostos/blob/master/lib/tasks/nostos.rake).

Code for `transaction.rb` can be found [here](https://github.com/bricestacey/nostos/blob/master/app/models/transaction.rb).

Comment: Can you provide the code for `nostos.rake`?

Comment: Also code for `transaction.rb` and `record.rb` from nostos-source-illiad might be needed. The answer may be found from `transaction.rb` line 65.

Comment: Code for record.rb can be found [here](https://github.com/bricestacey/nostos-source-illiad/blob/master/lib/nostos-source-illiad/record.rb) (I could only add 2 links above as a new user - sorry!)

Answer (score 0):

Upon further review, this issue appears to have been due to an invalid set of credentials being passed in. Resolving this removed the above messages. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: wat u mean by resolving credentials ?